# Compiling a flat library?

Tags: gcc

I'd like to compile a set of functions into a *flat library* for lack of a better term. There are a bunch of functions like

```
// add.c
int add (int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

// multiply.c
int multiply (int a, int b) {
    int result = 0;

    if (a >= 0)
        for (; a > 0; --a) result = add(result, b);
    else
        for (; a < 0; ++a) result = add(result, b);

    return result;
}

// double.c
int two = 2;
int double_ (int x) {
    return multiply(x, two);
}
```

and the compiled binary shall have

1. no `main` or `__start` entry points (it's a library, not an executable),
2. only instructions and data, no headers,
3. position-independent code,
4. no external dependencies (I'm not using any external libraries, but GCC appears to always include standard library stuff, which I don't need), and
5. little to no padding (i.e. no excessive amounts of null bytes for page/sector alignment)

And to be able to call the functions from outside the binary I either need to know their offsets from the beginning of the binary, **or** have a jump table at the beginning of the binary.

---

Using GCC points 3 and 4 can probably be achieved with `-fPIC` and `-nostdlib`. And if the functions were independent of each other I could achieve 5. by simply compiling the files separately and concatenating them manually which would also give me the function offsets, but here the functions are not independent of each other, so I rely on GCC to stich together the functions with minimal padding. For point 2 there is probably some `objcopy --oformat binary` trick or something similar. But I have no clue how to get point 1 to work. So far every single guide I've found online is for compiling custom/"hello world" kernels all of which are executables and have entry points. And if I don't provide an entry point `ld` complains that the symbol `__start` cannot be found. Furthermore, I don't know how to get the function offsets of the compiled binary or how to tell GCC to include a jump table (whichever of the two is possible).

Any ideas on how to compile the example above so that the compiled binary satisfies points 1 through 5 and is callable from outside the binary (either by offsets or via a jump table at the beginning)?

Answer (score 0):

After realizing that my requirements kinda look like compiling stuff for embedded devices with little storage, I looked up how firmware is compiled for embedded devices and found out that the linker can be finely tuned with [linker scripts](https://users.informatik.haw-hamburg.de/%7Ekrabat/FH-Labor/gnupro/5_GNUPro_Utilities/c_Using_LD/ldLinker_scripts.html). I ended up writing my own linker script that looks like this:

```
// File: link.ld
OUTPUT(test.bin);
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary);

SECTIONS {
    .text 0 : {
        add.o(.text);
        multiply.o(.text);
        double.o(.text);
    }
    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(*)
    }
}
```

Now, I can compile my source code with

```
gcc -c -fPIC -nostartfiles -nostdlib add.c multiply.c double.c
ld -M -T link.ld
```

where the first line compiles (`-c`) the source code into position-independent (`-fPIC`) object files (`*.c` -> `*.o`) without standard library (`-nostartfiles -nostdlib`), and the second line basically takes the `.text` sections of the object files and concatenates them, and prints out (`-M`) the section layout of the output file including the offsets of all symbols.